# malloc keeps returning the same address

Tags: c, pointers

I'm using `malloc` to create a struct. When I'm trying to create the struct in main, the `malloc` returns two different pointers, but when I'm doing the same inside a function the `malloc` returns the same pointer twice.
Here is my code:

```
typedef struct etf_t{                                                          
    int number;                                                                
    char* symbol;                                                              
    float initialPrice;                                                        
    List stocks;                                                               
}*Etf;                                                                         

Etf etfCreate(int number, char* name){                                         
    if (name == NULL || number <= 0){                                          
        return NULL;                                                           
    }                                                                          
    Etf etf = malloc(sizeof(*etf));                                            
    if (etf == NULL){                                                          
        return NULL;                                                           
    }                                                                          
    etf->stocks = listCreate(stockCopy, stockDestroy);                         
    if (etf->stocks == NULL){                                                  
        free(etf);                                                             
        return NULL;                                                           
    }                                                                          
    etf->number = number;                                                      
    etf->symbol = copyString(name);                                            
    etf->initialPrice=0;                                                       
    return etf;                                                                
}
```

Inside the function I just call it as:

```
Etf etf=etfCreate(etfID,etfName);
```

and then inserting it into a Map (by pointer).
I'm not destroying the `etf` anywhere in the code, so I don't know why the `malloc` is using the same address in the next function call.

EDIT:
I added printf after the malloc and here what im getting:

> Adrress: 000000000023FCF8
>   Adrress: 000000000023FCF8

print command is

```
printf("Adrress: %p\n",(void*)&etf);
enter code here
```

Comment: if i wasnt clear enought, etf is the pointer that malloc returns twice

Comment: Can you show the code that makes you think the pointer is same?

Comment: One malloc - one return value. Ps. should it be `malloc(sizeof(etf_t))`, What does `listCreate` do

Comment: Add a printf immediately after the malloc. I bet you will find it is not the same.

Comment: '(void*)&etf' is not what you think it is.

Comment: Please create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

Comment: @EdHeal, no, `malloc(sizeof *etf)` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Quentin- yes it is but not that readable

Answer (score 8):

Your code to print the pointer is incorrect.

```
printf("Adrress: %p\n",(void*)&etf)
```

`etf` is a pointer, so `&etf` is giving you the address of where that pointer is stored in memory. Which is the same on both calls.

You just want to print the pointer, so try:

```
printf("Address: %p\n",(void*)etf)
```

Comment: did this and im getting: Adrress: 0000000000281830
Adrress: 0000000000281910

Comment: OK, so a result, then..  Why not accept Graham's answer?

Comment: @edenbd Okay, so it prints two slightly different addresses now... What's the problem?

Comment: when im doing this: mapPut(house->etfs,&etfID,etf) //when house is the map and etfID is the key. and then im trying to print etf->symbol and i get the same symbol again and again, even though the key is different

Comment: That's a different issue. Can't really help with that without seeing the rest of the code. Suggest you check all the values in the debugger.

Comment: Graham completely and explicitly answered your question.  You should accept it now.  SO is a Q&A site, and 'serially fix all my problems before you get an accept' approach is contrary to SO purpose and policy.